# Image not loading from server in mozilla and safari browsers and image name is in arabic format.appering ???? marks insted of arabic text?

Tags: actionscript-3, arabic, flash-cs6, image-loading

I am using flash cs 6 and as3. i am loading image from server. url is ......../....../images/باجندوح.png.
am getting image when ever i enter this url in browser.but am running my code from flash builder am getting this error

```
"Error opening URL '..../...../images/باجندوح.png'
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed"
```

.image is there in server folder .and in browser also it is loding in chrome but in mozilla and safari it is creating problem.appering ????? marks insted of arabic name.
my code is :

```
var imgUrl:String = "...../........../images/باجندوح.png";
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest(imgUrl));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, infoIOErrorEvent);
```

Note:image name is in arabic format..if the image name is in english it is working fine.

Comment: Your image URL is not accessible to us. Host it in a place where we can access it to allow debugging, and update your question accordingly.

Comment: recently i realized that.in chrome browser it is working fine.getting problem for mozilla and safari browser in windows also.getting ????.png insted of arabic text.@ Gurtej Singh.

Comment: recently i realized that.in chrome browser it is working fine.getting problem for mozilla and safari browser in windows also.getting ????.png insted of arabic text.@ Gurtej Singh

Comment: Yes, I tried it from a flex AIR project and the same code works, but it does not work from a AS3 project. This is interesting. The url is not getting resolved correctly. Any chance you can rename this to a english file name?

Comment: No.I have to use arabic name only.I tink it is browser compatability problem (i tink problem with flash player version).@Gurtej Singh

Comment: I was able to solve it finally :) The solution was to url encode the arabic part of the name before making the call. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the URL is not being resolved properly since there is arabic text and it's resolving to ?????.png. The solution was to encode the arabic part of the name before sending the request, and I was able to hit the image and get a successful response.

The encoding (`encodeURI`) correctly resolves the URL to:

http://......./......./...../%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%AD.png

Use the following code:

```
var imgUrl:String = "http://....../..../...../";
var imgPart:String = "باجندوح";
var finalURL:String = imgUrl + encodeURI(imgPart) + ".png";
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, infoIOErrorEvent);
loader.load(new URLRequest(finalURL));
```

Hope this resolves your question.

Answer (score -1):

Probably as3 can't read arabic letters and can't find the way. So you should add arabic letters on your project.

You can probably look here hope it helps :
[Arabic text in as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652021/arabic-text-in-as3)

Comment: This does not seem like a right answer. OP is trying to load an image with arabic text in the file name, and not write arabic text in text fields.

Comment: well miss understanding tho sorry :/